# How to pass a dictionary from one viewcontroller to anotherviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uistoryboard

I have 2 view controllers connected by using segue.How can i pass one dictionary {"fist":1,"second":2} in the secondviewcontroller to first viewcontroller.

Comment: I suggest starting by reading the hundreds of answers to that question that are already on this site.  If they don't work for you, explain what's different about your situation.

Comment: Pass it up the stack in `prepareForSegue:` pass it down the stack through a protocol.

Comment: I am new in iOS and objective c..I already tried some answers available in stack overflow. Unfortunately i did not get the output.I tried to get some help from others for solve my problem if you like to help me just help otherwise just ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add identifier to your segue in storyboard.
In yout source view controller override prepareForSegue: method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOURIDENTIFIER"]) { //<-YOURIDENTIFIER the same as you set up in storyboard

        UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        // You should cast destination view controller to your custom view controller sub class:
       //YourViewController *vc = (YourViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
       // Pass the data
       vc.myDictionary = @{{"fist":1,"second":2};
       // I assume you have property myDictionary in YourViewController class
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Can you mark as answered so maybe someone else will find it useful.